# Why my Google Analytics ecommerce transfer doesnt get registered?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

I have ecommerce configured on my analytics page (very basically), and I'm trying to send a transaction based on [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce).

The code being rendered on my browser when the transaction is done, looks like this:

Head: (Jade)

```
script(async='', src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX-1')
script.
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX-1');
```

Body, further down

```js
var order = {
  "_id":"59e3cf363095221100edb909",
  "frete":{"frete":1350},
  "payment":{
    "Payment":{
      "Amount":5550
    }
  },
  "products":[
    {"product":{
      "_id":"58eb9dfb147a3b1a000e0d9c",
      "price":4200,
      "category":"58988fd4b2ae511a00eff884",
      "name":"CAIXA DE TRUFAS"
    },
    "quantity":1
    }]
  };

var itens = [];

var product
var item;
for(var i  = 0; i < order.products.length; i ++){
  product = order.products[i].product
  item = {
    "id": product['_id'],
    "name": product.name,
    "category": product.category.name,
    "quantity": order.products[i].quantity,
    "price": product.price / 100
  }
  itens.push(item);
}

gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": order['_id'],
  "affiliation": "Frutacor",
  "value": order.payment.Payment.Amount / 100,
  "currency": "BRL",
  "shipping": order.frete.frete / 100,
  "items": itens
});
```

The thing is, nothing shows up on my Analytics page and I don't know why. Researching about it, I've encountered things about analytics, ga, Google Tag Manager (GTM), and the new gtag.js, which is the one I'm using

Comment: Have you properly configured Google Tag Manager with a Google Analytics tag that supports enhanced e-commerce? A connection needs to be made from the tag manager to the actual analytics tag.

Comment: Yes I did. As i posted on the answer below, this code does work, its just that it might take a while to register. Also, Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics got merged into gtag.js, from what I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code from the question does work. Its just that analytics may take up to 48h to display it